# imagenes .png generando lag | python tkinter canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Estoy usando el canvas de tkinter en python, y tengo el problema de que las imágenes .png generan un lag extremo cuando las dibujo en el canvas. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de que no den tanto lag. El código resumido que uso para ponerlas en la interfáz es:

```
while True:

    canvas.delete("all")

    Image=PhotoImage(file="archivo.png")
    canvas.create_image(x, y, image=Image)

    root.update()
```

por si sirve de algo aquí está el código completo:

```
from tkinter import *; import random



root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root, bg="#052b05")
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand="True")


x, y, xvel, yvel= 600,500,0,0

treesx, treesy, treesnumber=[],[],[]

for i in range(random.randint(1,1)):   # original: 50-150

    treesx.append(random.randint(-50,50))    # original: -5000, 5000
    treesy.append(random.randint(-50,50))    # original: -5000, 5000
    treesnumber.append(random.choice(["arbol1 krita.png", "arbol2 krita.png", "arbol3 krita.png"]))


KeysPressed=[]

def NewKey(event):

    global KeysPressed

    if event.char not in KeysPressed:

        KeysPressed.append(event.char)




def DelKey(event):

    global KeysPressed

    KeysPressed.pop(KeysPressed.index(event.char))


root.bind("<KeyPress>", NewKey) # key detection

root.bind("<KeyRelease>", DelKey)


while True:

    canvas.delete("all")


    canvas.create_oval(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2+20,root.winfo_screenheight()/2+20,root.winfo_screenwidth()/2-20,root.winfo_screenheight()/2-20, fill="black")



    for i in treesx:

        if 1600 > treesx[treesx.index(i)] + x > -200 and 1200 > treesy[treesx.index(i)] + y > -200:

            Image=PhotoImage(file=treesnumber[treesx.index(i)]) # set Image to a random tree png file.


            canvas.create_image(treesx[treesx.index(i)]+x, treesy[treesx.index(i)]+y, image=Image) # draw Image in canvas





    if "w" in KeysPressed: # movement

        yvel += 1

    if "s" in KeysPressed:

        yvel -= 1

    if "d" in KeysPressed:

        xvel += 1

    if "a" in KeysPressed:

        xvel -= 1

    x -= xvel # movement
    y += yvel

    xvel /= 1.02 # friction
    yvel /= 1.02


    root.update()
```

explicación del código: lo primero que hago es crear 3 variables treesx, treesy, y treesnumber que almacenan la info de las imágenes .png (las cuáles son árboles). Luego creo el bind que hace que te puedas mover con wasd, e inmediatamente después de eso empieza el while True que tiene la orden de dibujar las imágenes (el canvas.create_oval es para dibujar un muñeco que hace de personaje, no es importante).

PD: -las imágenes que estoy usando son de 48 kb, probé con imágenes de distinto tamaño pero no resolví nada. También probé a pasarlas a xbm y aún así no solucioné el problema (además de que se veían super extrañas).
    -No se confundan con el "for i in range()" para dibujar las imágenes, sólo estoy dibujando 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la lógica que usas (crear una imagen nueva por cada iteración y luego eliminarla) consume demasiados recursos. Mejor c**rea las imagenes una sola vez y actualízalas** (muevelas)

Un poquito "arreglando" la forma en la que computas la lógica, habría que guardar las imagenes en una lista, y solo crearlas una vez (moverlas **afuera** del loop principal `while True`):

```
f=[] #Lista donde vas a guardar una referencia a imagenes del canvas
for i, tree in enumerate(treesx):
    Image = PhotoImage(file=treesnumber[i])
    f.append(canvas.create_image(tree+x, treesy[i]+y, image=Image))

canvas.create_oval(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2+20, root.winfo_screenheight()/2+20,
                        root.winfo_screenwidth()/2-20, root.winfo_screenheight()/2-20, fill="black")
```

Por lo que finalmente en el loop, en lugar de instanciar miles de imagenes, obtienes:

```
while True:

    for imagen in f:
        posactual = canvas.coords(imagen) #esto te da la coordenada (x,y)
        canvas.move(imagen, xvel, yvel)
```

Ahora el problema es que... Va demasiado rápido!! Por lo que antes de este for, sería bueno añadir un concepto conocido como ***game loop***, y limitar las actualizaciones por segundo con un pequeño cálculo de delta de tiempo entre frames, y un `time.sleep()` para que el programa se detenga por unos milisegundos; finalmente quedando así:

```
import time
FPS = 60
ultframe = time.time()
while True:
    actualframe = time.time()
    dt = actualframe - ultframe
    ultframe = actualframe
    sleepTime = (1.0/FPS) - dt

    if sleepTime > 0:
        time.sleep(sleepTime)

    for imagen in f:
        posactual = canvas.coords(imagen)
        canvas.move(imagen, xvel, yvel)
```

Aquí, ya no necesitas hacer crecer o decrecer `x` o `y`, dado que el canvas mismo tiene el método `canvas.coords()`, donde puedes sacar las coordenadas del objeto. `canvas.move(obj, x, y)` te permite mover el objeto relativamente (posicionX + x, posicionY + y)

Adicionalmente, y como regla general, pienso que deberías estructurar tu programa para que use clases, en lugar de hacer uso de variables globales, y no se haga tanto lío.

Comment: muchas gracias, me salvaste. Hay algún método que mueva los objetos del canvas a una coordenada específica en vez de moverlos relativamente? gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Justo eso estaba buscando, no logré encontrarlo, pero a lo mejor puedes hacer una función que lo convierta (debería ser la posición X actual - la posición X deseada, solamente, igual con Y)

Comment: ya descubri como hacerlo: ___canvas.move(tree, treex-treex * 2, treey-treey * 2)___ para que el objeto vaya a x0 y0, y ___canvas.move(tree, x, y)___ para que vaya a las coordenadas que quiera

Comment: Lo encontré!!! En lugar de pasarlo al 0,0 y luego al x,y que quieres, simplemente puedes poner `canvas.coords(tree,x,y)`

Comment: gracias, me has hecho la vida más simple jaja